# Handling tuple in SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to query a sqlite3 database to check if a unique user id exists. How it works is the user clicks the Tkinter button and then inputs their idTag value. The command `reader.read()` is used to get the tag's value. Once the user has inputted their idTag the datacheck(): function will check the userID column of the database to find a matching idTag and userID .

`idTag` returns a tuple. For an example the `idTag` value would look like this (123456, q5gln7b8dhe). I am interested in checking the second vale of the the `idTag` so the *q5gln7b8dhe* value. This is the user uid.

My issue is the `for x in row_returned` constantly true even if the idTag does not match a stored userID. I think the c.fetchone() is constantly pulling the data with out making sure the idTag and userID value match. Or that no data is being pulled at all.
**Error Message :** `for x in row_returned :` , `TypeError : 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

```
def chk():

# Function that handels getting User ID 
def tagScanner():
    # Get user id value
    idTag = reader.read()
    # If tag is scanned 
    if idTag:
        # call Database function to check returned idTag
        dataCheck(idTag)
        return idTag

# Function handles SQLite3 Database     
def dataCheck(idTag):
    Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
    # cursor
    c = Database.cursor()
    # Check if the idTag maches a value in the userID column of sqlite DB
    query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE userID = ?'

    c.execute(query, (str(idTag),))
    row_returned = c.fetchone()
    for x in row_returned :
        print('Checking for User')
        #checking the second value in tulpe
        if x[1] == idTag:
            print('User Verified')
        else:
            print('User does not exist')

        Database.close()

# Call scanning function 
tagScanner()
```

Comment: if `idTag[1] == 'q5gln7b8dhe': #do something` wont like this work?. Also i dont think `fetchall()` will ever return `None`, I have seen it return `[]` but not `None`

Comment: @CoolCloud No this will not work because the `idTag` value will be different for each user.

Comment: Give an example of `row_returned`, say `print(row_returned)` and let me know

Comment: @CoolCloud My mistake, actually just printing out `row_returned `  returns `[ ]` . So I guess the issue is in `if row_returned is not None ` since it is not returning the query results.

Comment: Yes `if row_returned is not None` will always be truthy because its never `None` its either `[]` or `[(...),....]`, so give some more example if your looking for a solution

Comment: @CoolCloud I have updated the code to reflect current changes. I believe that the issue is no data is being returned from the database. The issue has to be right after `query`. Every time a `idTag` is inputted it just prompts `None` in the console. The code runs, no errors occur.

Comment: Everything seems fine, just try `print(row_returned` and lemme know what it returns

Comment: @CoolCloud I got an error this time. `for x in row_returned : ` `TypeError : 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: which means `row_returned` is `None`, means `fetchone()` can return `None` but not `fetchall()` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud just tried `fetchall()` emplace of one. No error but it just prints out `checking for user ` in the console and stops.

Comment: _checking for user?_ from there did that come from. For the last time, provide an example of what `print(row_returned)` is, so its easier for me to help you

Comment: @CoolCloud As stated in the 4th comment `print('row_returned')` prints out no data, nothing is printed out when it is printed just empty [ ]. The code above has been updated, _Checking for User_ has been added.

Comment: That means your query is incorrect, what are the data inside the database? Usually it can happen like this due to difference in datatypes

Comment: @CoolCloud the  `userID` is being set like this `userID  text`. I wonder if setting the database to store a text value is causing the issue due to the value containing some integers. For a example, a   `userID` value would look like this _gfg45wid7di3hd7_ .

Comment: I believe that is fine, it might be something else, probably where you say `str(idTag)` ?